# How do you keep your inventory upon death in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft PE on my tablet, and I dislike the fact that I drop all items in my inventory upon death. Is there anything built in or a mod that would allow me to keep my inventory when I die?

Comment: I feel like this might be a duplicate, but since it's PE, I'm not sure

Comment: Try [this website](https://forums.pocketmine.net/plugins/keepinventory.899/)

Answer (score 3):

With the new update, a new command has been added to allow you to do so, which is `/gamerule keepinventory true`. Other options include MCPE Master, which is a launcher app, as it has a switch on its drop down menu which allows you to keep items and xp.

Answer (score 0):

### It really depends

If you're playing on survival, then that is a natural thing to do. If you're playing on creative, then no. Since the new update, I don't think you can die anymore by the void in creative, so it might be impossible to even die in creative.

Comment: You still die from the under void in creative in just a couple of seconds. A quick proof would be /teleport <your name> 0 0 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's imposible to keep everything when you die it's best to just keep the important items in a chest or if you can't then remember where you died and collect it again unless you want to play it safe and switch to creative mode and just fly to where you died and pick it all up without needing to worry about mobs. Or you can go into creative mode and re-add the lost items to your inventory and act like the death never happend. (I'm guilty of doing the last one many times)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you can't. Long answer is, when you die, you naturally drop whatever you are holding. If you manage to get to where you died in time, though, you can pick up any items you had dropped... Unless you fell into lava or into a cactus hole and died there, then you can say goodbye to your items as the lava/cactus would destroy any items which touch them.

There may be servers or Realms where your inventory is kept on death, but in Survival Single Player, you drop items.